# How to delete or change the words "My card" under my own name at the top of "Contacts"? (iOS 13.5.1)

Tags: iphone, ios, contacts

When I open "Contacts" on my iPhone XR running iOS 13.5.1, the person listed at the top is me. The index entry consists of three parts: my name in bold; an image I've chosen; and, under my name in smaller type, the words "My Card".

How can I delete or change the words "My Card"? (Note: this is all I want to change. I do not want to delete myself as a contact, or my name, or the image.)

Answer (score 1):

You can’t change those words. They are hard coded into the application and it shows them to identify which contact in the app identifies you.

If you don’t want that contact to be identified as you, go into the preferences for the contacts app and choose a different card under “My Info”. If that doesn’t work, you can delete the card and re-add it, but without choosing the card as your contact details.

Comment: Many thanks. The contact is already identified as special by being at the top, using big type, and having an image to its left. So is there no way to keep these features but lose (or change) the words "My Card"? I did the first thing you suggest, but all it does is put a contact at the top who isn't me, keeping the line saying "My Card", which isn't what I'm after. Isn't there a way to hack this?